# Wifi router and ADSL conflicts

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem, adsl, setup

I have adsl modem which is connected to internet.

I can access internet if i connect laptop directly to adsl modem.

laptop > adsl

Now i plugged in my wifi router (cisco e900) to adsl modem and none wifi devices have net via this setup:

wifi devices> wifi router > adsl

I saw many posts for the same , that changing the IP of the wifi to other than adsl.modem will solve the problem, but it doesnt for me; may be i am wrong at some steps.

What futher I should do?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Have you setup the router? They are simple, but not typically "plug and play".  According to their site, it uses a `Setup CD` or you can [follow these instructions](http://www.linksys.com/gr/support-article?articleNum=140176) if you don't have the CD.

Comment: Thanks,this post helped me to get into my wireless. I flashed cisco fw over ddwrt and then went through dsl to router steps, changed router IP to other than the modem and it started giving output